# Is it possible to put in order React useEffects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

In 2nd. `useEffect` I want to return `experiences` using `resume.id` which is coming from 1st `useEffect`. But I guess they are working in the same time so before returns `resume` in 1st `useEffect`, 2nd one is working and it returns `undefined`. How can I fix this or is there a any way to write better code ?

```
const { authUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [resume, setResume] = useState({});
  const [experience, setExperience] = useState([]);

  let resumeService = new ResumeService();
  let resumeExperienceService = new ResumeExperienceService();

  useEffect(() => {
    resumeService
      .getResumeByCandidateId(authUser.id)
      .then((result) => setResume(result.data.data[0]));
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    resumeExperienceService
      .getExperiencesByResumeId(resume.id)
      .then((result) => setExperience(result.data.data));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the state that named 'resume' to the useEffect.
That means second useEffect would run after every setResume call

```js
const { authUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [resume, setResume] = useState({});
  const [experience, setExperience] = useState([]);

  let resumeService = new ResumeService();
  let resumeExperienceService = new ResumeExperienceService();

  useEffect(() => {
    resumeService
      .getResumeByCandidateId(authUser.id)
      .then((result) => setResume(result.data.data[0]));
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    resumeExperienceService
      .getExperiencesByResumeId(resume.id)
      .then((result) => setExperience(result.data.data));
  }, [resume]);
```